# Assign class constructor to a new constructor with parameter in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor, dynamic-arrays

I create a class type Test and constructor with parameter, however, when I want to assign the constructor I create to a new constructor through the function f, the program crashes! Did anybody know why!?

The code:

```
class Test
{
  public:
    int number;
    int *a;
    Test(int n){
        a = new int[n];
    }
    ~Test(){
        delete []a;
    }
};

Test f(Test Ft1)
{   
     // Do something.
     return Ft1;
}

int main()
{   
    Test t1(3);
    t1.number = 5;
    Test t2 = f(t1);    
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are deleting twice the same array `a` when `t1` and `t2` destructors are called: 
`t1` and `t2` have their member variable `a` pointing to the same memory location. When you do `Test t2 = f(t1)`, a copy of `t1` is created and is assigned to `t2`. You did not define a specific copy constructor, so the compiler defined it implicitly for you. However it simply copies the value of `a` (and does not do a `new` allocation as you might expect).

As best practice, I would recommend to add your own:
- copy constructor
- copy assignment
(cf `rule of three`)

Concerning the variable member `a` design:
- If you want `t1` and `t2` to point to the same array, then you can use `shared_ptr`
- If you want `t1` and `t2` to have their own array, then it would be simpler to use a `vector<int>` for `a`

Edit: in case you need to use a raw pointer, here is a quick example of how you can manage the memory in copy constructor and operator assignment. May I recommend you to read a  reference book about it (for instance `Effective C++ , chapter 11`)? It will explain you the key concepts and the pitfalls.

```
class Test{
public:
    int number;
    int *a;
    Test(int n){
        a = new int[n];
    }
    ~Test(){
        delete [] a;
    }
    Test(const Test& that)
    {
        int size = sizeof(that.a);
        a = new int[size];
        memcpy (a, that.a, sizeof(size));
    }
    Test& operator=(const Test& that)
    {
        if (this != &that)
        {
            delete [] a;
            int size = sizeof(that.a);
            a = new int[size];
            memcpy (a, that.a, sizeof(size));
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

Test f(Test Ft1){   
    //do something
    return Ft1;
}

int main(){ 
    Test t1(3);
    t1.number = 5;
    Test t2 = f(t1);
    // Test t3(t1);  // calls copy constructor
    // t3 = t1; // calls assignment operator
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: It is possible, but you need to manage the pointers in your copy constructor and copy assignment. IMHO, the design (2nd one)  i mentioned above is just easier to implement than manipulating raw pointer.

Comment: (following), for instance, here is a simple example of a copy constructor that manipulates the raw pointer:  `Test(const Test& that)
 {
  int size = sizeof(that.a);
  this->a = new int[size];
  memcpy (this->a, that.a, sizeof (size)) ;
 }`

Comment: Can you show me the complete code to realize my purpose? I am new to class, please. And thanks :)

Comment: @user2879534 i updated my answer. Later, you may want to use vector<int> and compare the implementations.

Comment: Haha your right! SO the vector don't have this problem ? cause, there is no pointer for vector ?

Comment: the vector hides this complexity. It manages internally the memory allocation, deallocation, reallocation...

Answer (score 2):

The cause of your problem is that there is a thing called "binary copy". When special assignment/copy constructors are not defined, this binary copy kicks in. When one of your object gets copied over another, 2 different instances start own the same array because the pointer gets overwritten and the original array from the destination object gets leaked.

Compiler thinks that it is ok to copy contents of one object to another with a simple `memcpy()` (the picture is slightly more simplified but in essence what I write is correct). This is a constant source of problems, but this is how the language is defined. There is no way to do it any other way today. Tons of code are written and these tons expect exactly this.

First you need to decide what should happen with this array after copying. Should both objects `co-own` the array  of the source object, should this array be duplicated at this point or anything else. Once you decide this, you need to implement this strategy in the assignment/copy constructors.